# Is there a way to use render with an existing controller instance rather than letting it create a new one?

Tags: ember.js

I have an AnswersValidationController and which I use in this manner:

{{render 'answers-validation' answersValidation}}

and

this.controllerFor('answersValidation') OR needs: ['answersValidation'].

Regardless of the order in which needs/controllerFor is used, the 'render' and controllerFor/needs result in two different instances of the same controller 'answersValidation'. Why? How do I prevent that?
Note: the render and controllerFor/needs are used in the same route. Also, even if I use {{render 'answers-validation'}} - it creates another controller instance.

Is there an alternative to {{render}} in which case I can use the singleton controller instance?

Answer (score 1):

That's the intended behaviour. By default Ember controllers are singletons however the

```
{{render}}
```

helper will create it's own instance of the controller if a model is provided. That way you can have multiple times the same controller on the same page with different model for each one. You can check the render documentation for more details : http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/

Edit: To answer the new title, to render an existing controller with {{render}}, you can't specify a new model.

Comment: Is there an alternative to {{render}} in which case I can use the singleton controller instance?

Comment: It really depends on your use case. Why can't the standard route/controller works for you ?